# mysql passing array into LIKE without loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
$serach=array('abc','def','ghi');

$num=count($search);
for($n=0, $n<$num, $n++){
  $sql .= LIKE % $search[$n] % OR ;
}
$sql=substr_replace($sql,"",-3);//REMOVE LAST OR


SELECT * FROM store_main WHERE name :sql...
```

i need pass an array into query LIKE, i have use loop to create the statement and put into the query, my question is, is any way do it without loop, so i can make my query more simple.

Comment: You can you `IN` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
echo "%".str_replace(",","% OR %",implode(",", $array))."%";
```

**Output**

> %lastname% OR %email% OR %phone%

Refer
[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and
[str-replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like so:

```
$serach = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi');
$sql .= "`name` LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR `name` LIKE '%", $serach) . "%' ";
```

produces:

```
`name` LIKE '%abc%' OR `name` LIKE '%def%' OR `name` LIKE '%ghi%'
```

OR you can use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). This one could be a bit slower depending on how many array elements you have and/or your table/database's efficiency.

```
$serach = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi');
$sql .= "`name` REGEXP '" . implode("|" $serach) . "' ";
```

produces:

```
`name` REGEXP 'abc|def|ghi'
```